# New firebase project for an old Flutter app which already has another firebase project

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We have a Flutter app that was released more than a year ago in the Google Play Store and App Store.

This project has now come under maintenance mode. During this period, we have migrated the application to the latest Flutter version, and upgraded the respective packages as well.

The app also had push notifications integrated, and used Firebase Cloud Messaging for that.

Unfortunately, for us, the app does not have enough documentation. And we do not know what Firebase Console credentials were used to create this project. Since, we lack the credentials, we decided the next alternative would be to create a new Firebase project and integrate its configuration into our application.

We have used Flutter Fire CLI to help us with this process. The rest of the setup to handle foreground/background notifications are also put in place.

We tried to test the notifications feature on Android and iOS real devices, but the Firebase's "Send test notification" using generated device-specific FCM tokens still does not receive anything in the app or phone. We tried sending a notification to users of a particular country, rather than targeting a particular FCM token, and we do receive it in Android. (And yes, in both the cases, the app is in the background)

Why doesn't the "Test notification" feature work here?

Also, can anyone let us know if we will be facing any repercussions with the approach we have taken by creating a new Firebase project for an existing app, and if yes, how we can mitigate it?